# Configure nginx to serve static files in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, yard

I've generated YARD documentation, and it lives in `/gem/doc/`. I'd like to be able to serve that in my Rails app at `/api/`. I'd like to avoid symlinking to it in the `/public` directory, so I'm trying to configure nginx to serve these files.

Here's what I've tried so far, but it doesn't seem to be doing anything. I created a new file, `config/nginx.conf`, with the following:

```
server {
  listen 80;

  location /api/ {
    root gem/doc/;
    index index.html;
  }
}
```

How do I configure nginx to do this within my Rails app?

Comment: How are you feeding your application to nginx?

Comment: I have my rails app configured with unicorn, which I believe runs on top of nginx. All I did was add unicorn to the gemfile

Comment: I guess you are using some default `nginx.conf` provided by unicorn... Anyway, you need to assign absolute path to the `root` field for the `location` directive. So, `/your/rails/app/gem/doc` or wherever...